# Creating a user session with AngularJS and DreamFactory

Tags: angularjs, sessionid

I'm trying to make a simple login function for my AngularJS application. I'm using Dream Factory for my backend server database and I can't seem to be able to create a session from my login-function.

This is the factory I have set up:

```
dfdevApp.factory('SessionService', function($resource, $q) {
  var sessionResource = $resource('https://dsp-myusername.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/user/session', {}, 
      { update: { method: 'PUT' }, query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false} });
  return {
    create: function (user) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          sessionResource.save(user, function (result) {
              deferred.resolve(result);
          }, function (error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
          });
          return deferred.promise;
      }
  }
});
```

And this is the code from my controller:

```
     // $scope.ting = Liste.get()
$scope.user = {'email' : '', 'password': ''};

$scope.login = function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.user));
$scope.user = SessionService.create(JSON.stringify($scope.user), function(success) {
    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
    $location.path('/');
}, function(error) {
    $scope.loginError = true;
});
```

};
});

I get a 400 every time I try to post.

Answer (score 3):

Your post should be like this one:

```
{"email":"you@youremail.com","password":"yourpassword"}
```

Also don't forget to include your app_name in the URL or as a header (in this case, call it X-DreamFactory-Application-Name).

You can find more info here:

http://blog.dreamfactory.com/blog/bid/326379/Getting-Started-with-the-DreamFactory-API

I also built an "SDK" which handles all this for you.

https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/javascript-sdk